# React native camera don't work well in IOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm developing a mobile application for IOS using react native and I want to take images using react native image picker package but I got this error in Xcode console when I try to open camera for the second time:

[Camera] Attempted to change to mode Portrait with an unsupported device (BackWideDual). Auto device for both positions unsupported, returning Auto device for same position anyway (BackAuto).